# Fuel tank leakage

Tags: fuel-system, leak

I have this sudden fuel leakage from the base of the fuel tank of my benelli tnt 25. I am clearly unable to cite the reason. The leakge is present upto a certain level of fuel.Is it safe to drive the bike

Comment: I would never recommend driving anything that's leaking fuel.  How old is the bike - could the tank be rusty? Or perhaps you've got a hose that's rotted?

Comment: So if the tank explodes - it takes your future family with it...  "is it safe to drive..?". **NO** - fix the leak **before** using the bike again.